# Angular form update form values set parent to multiple child pages

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

parent page

```
<app-pa #child></app-pa>

@ViewChildren('child') paList:QueryList<PAComponent>;
```

child page  - have few form fields.

Parent side we have List of objects.Within that have List of child objects.
How to pass child values parent to child (multiple scenario).

Comment: why not use `@Input` decorator

Comment: have multiple parents and multiple childrens. parent ts looping child.